# NPC AI articles for walking and fighting?

Tags: algorithm, ai, npc

I'm looking to learn about NPC AI to solve a problem how an NPC should walk e.g. walking straight and then turn at a wall. Perhaps I can program it to walk along a line but then I still would not know how to make the NPC do more complex. An article I found is linked.

http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/

Can you link something more that could solve my problem?

### Update

I found this question constructive:
[How to handle walking into walls?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23157/how-to-handle-walking-into-walls)

Comment: Voting to close;  This question is asking for links, rather than asking for answers.

Comment: @TrevorPowell Lengthy code can be posted to pastebin but I don't think you even answer with code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may want to investigate more fundamental concepts behind AI systems in general. The AI for a game is usually made up of many different components and decision making processes that are each custom tailored to their own particular context.

[http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Game-Example-Mat-Buckland/dp/1556220782/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1360073834&sr=8-1&keywords=game+AI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1556220782)

This is a link to a book that myself, and a number of fellow graduate students find quite useful. The link you provided has some neat information at it, and quite a few links to other bits of useful information.

Answer (score 2):

You could also been interested in [this](http://gdmag.com/issue/2011/CareerGuide) number of Game Career Guide: check the article at page 13, "Getting there from here". I know that's a simple introduction to AI, but it's well written and, if you have to start from the basis, it could be very useful. More than that, it provides some resources at the end.